# Using events in between React components with distant relationships

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I have one component which when clicked needs to make a get request and change the content of a completely different component. I made a drawing to show their relationship:
[image]

I was told to use Flux to do this, but to be completely honest I am completely lost trying to learn them, and did not like what I saw. To make matters even more complicated, this project does not use npm or node, which seems to be almost essential accrding to all the tutorials, so if I really must use Flux, how can I get away with it without npm and all the require calls?
Here is my current relevant code:

```
var AboutItem = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(event){
        //do something to update ChangeLogData!
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {this.props.list.map(function (listValue,key) {
                    var link = currentUrl + "/changelog/" + listValue.split(' ')[0];
                    return <ListGroupItem key={key} className="module"
                                                    bsStyle="warning"
                                                    onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        {listValue}
                    </ListGroupItem>
                }, this)}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
});

var ChangeLogData = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            content: {},
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                 Something from AboutItem
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do (that I can think of) is to make the handleClick a function in `<About />` component and make it update its `log` state. Then, from that component you can pass this function as `props` to `<AboutItem/>` component and pass the state of the log down to the tree as `props` as well. So, whenever the state changes, the `<ChangeLogData />` will receive it and re-render.

Answer (score 0):

In React, data downstreams and events upstream. What you need to do is

1. Make `About` component stateful and contain a certain property of state, say `shouldUpdateLog`. By default, it's false.
2. Pass a function to `AboutItem` component in form of a prop from its parent, `About` component. The function will update `About` component's state.
3. Pass the property of `About` component's state down to `ChangeLogData` and depend on its value on any component update. If you put this data in `render`, that would be easy, but since you need to fire a function, you'll need to listen to every `componentDidUpdate` of `ChangeLogData`.

So, first, `About`:

```
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      shouldUpdateLog: false
    };
  }

  handleUpdate() {
    this.setState({
      shouldUpdateLog: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AboutItem onUpdate={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)} />
        <ChangeLog>
          <ChangeLogData shouldUpdateLog={this.state.shouldUpdateLog} />
        </ChangeLog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the `AboutItem`:

```
class AboutItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onUpdate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, the `ChangeLogData`:

```
class ChangeLogData extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.shouldUpdateLog) {
      // call that function!
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think we are almost there... I should probably mention one more thing: AboutItem are actually various buttons that are dynamically made and each button would give me a link to a different JSON file which I would then need to make a get request to in the ChangeLogData and display that data. I still have no idea how to get to that from here.